# meaning of "the field of the fullers"

Tags: meaning, context

Accursed be the Sea-folk, and accursed be all they who traffic with them. And as for him who for love's sake forsook God, and so lieth here with his leman slain by God's judgment, take up his body and the body of his leman, and bury them in the corner of the **Field of the Fullers**, and set no mark above them, nor sign of any kind, that none may know the place of their resting. For accursed were they in their lives, and accursed shall they be in their deaths also.'

I can't figure out the above phrase of "Filed of the Fullers".

Does this have something to do with the Bible ?
And what it really means?

In the bible : Isaiah 36:2

2And the king of Assyria sent Rabshakeh from Lachish to Jerusalem to King Hezekiah with a large army. And he stood by the conduit of the upper pool on the highway of **the fuller's field**.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It appears the biblical clay mine near Hinnom is variously translated as both "fullers field" and "potters field".  Both of these occupations use clay, and clay mines are no good for agriculture.  "Fullers' earth" is a common name for [specific clays](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fuller%27s_earth).

[Potters field](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Potter%27s_field) is the more common name used in English for the unmarked burial ground for paupers, which is what this passage refers to.  As depicted in *Amadeus* Mozart was penniless at death and buried in a potters field or common grave.

Answer (score 1):

I think it refers to this place, ***[Fuller's field](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/fuller-s-field)***:

> - a spot near Jerusalem (2 Kings 18:17; Isa. 36:2; 7:3), on the side of the highway west of the city, not far distant from the "upper pool" at the head of the valley of Hinnom. ***Here the fullers pursued their occupation.***

***[Fuller:](http://www.biblestudytools.com/dictionary/fuller/)***

> - The word "full" is from the Anglo-Saxon fullian, meaning "to whiten." To full is to press or scour cloth in a mill. This art is one of great antiquity. Mention is made of "fuller's soap" ( Malachi 3:2 ), ***and of "the fuller's field" ( 2 Kings 18:17 )***. At his transfiguration our Lord's rainment is said to have been white "so as no fuller on earth could white them" ( Mark 9:3 ). En-rogel (q.v.), meaning literally "foot-fountain," has been interpreted as the "fuller's fountain," because there the fullers trod the cloth with their feet.

Comment: Mary Stewart in The Crystal Cave (1970) used _fuller_ to mean launderer also: "...no harm's done except your cloak will have to go to the **fullers** tomorrow."

Answer (score 0):

The text you've quoted is from the fairy tale **The Fisherman and His Soul** by Oscar Wilde - see [The Happy Prince and Other Fairy Tales](https://books.google.com.au/books?id=V6TDAgAAQBAJ&pg=PA115&lpg=PA115&dq=%22Accursed+be+the+Sea-folk,+and+accursed+be+all+they+who+traffic+with+them%22&source=bl&ots=UkWQ8JFibQ&sig=btaxPbHLGnbGS9-_WyoSX0V8oDE&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwi0hdmt5szNAhVEoZQKHRCyDioQ6AEILDAF#v=onepage&q=%22Accursed%20be%20the%20Sea-folk%2C%20and%20accursed%20be%20all%20they%20who%20traffic%20with%20them%22&f=false). While it's written in quasi-Biblical style, it's purely fiction. I haven't read the full fairy tale but I couldn't see any earlier mention of Fullers so I'm guessing it's simply a name that Wilde created.